# Html/css nav bar appears over fullscreen videojs in browser

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, navbar, video.js

I have searched everywhere but can't seem to find an answer to this. When playing videos in fullscreen the html navigation sits over the video in IE, Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari from both a Mac and a PC.
The site is http://www.david-bartlett.com Please look at the showreel page or the excerpts.

I'm a relative newbie I'm afraid, is this a css thing or a videojs issue ? Any ideas about how to fix it would be gratefully received.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `z-index` property in DB.css line 80:

```
#nav li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index:3000; /* this line causes the bug */        
}
```

I'm not sure about other browsers, but in Firefox, it's ok to simply remove that line.